# Python - Manipulation of values before writing to output

Tags: python

I am attempting(can) write the values of a dictionary to files. The values are wrote in the file with the below format.

```
>foo bar
>too you
```

So each `>` represents a value within the key(file is the key) and also a line in the file.

Can I manipulate the values so that my file looks like this? (below)

```
>foo
bar
>too
you
```

Simply taking the white space in-between the strings of each value and making it into a return, is this possible?

I know that I could always read in the file again and strip the lines... but there are 100+ files from the output of my script, makes sense to do this "return" during the generation of the files.

The part of my code in question:

```
for key, values in sequencelist.items():
with open(key, 'w') as out:
    for value in values:
        out.write(''.join(value) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for key, values in sequencelist.items():
    with open(key, 'w') as out:
        for value in values:
            out.write('\n'.join(value.split()))
```

Comment: *face palm* didn't think to try split. Thank you jamylak :) always the easy stuff. I am going to post a second question in a few that might be a little more challenging.